# Android Fragment Duplicate Objects in Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm trying to build an Android 4.0 App with the new fragments and action bar.
I'm doing well but I have a little problem now.

When I put a fragment inside a tab, and for example, a time picker in the fragment layout, in the emulator it will appear twice, one on top of the other.

Here is my code:

```
public class NetworksActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.networks);

    // setup Action Bar for tabs
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // instantiate fragment for the tab
    Fragment networksFragment = new NetworksFragment();
    // add a new tab and set its title text and tab listener
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Sensors")
            .setTabListener(new ActionTabListener(networksFragment)));
}}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/net_frag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="my.package.test.NetworksFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
public class NetworksFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.networks_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
public class ActionTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private NetworksFragment frag;

    // Called to create an instance of the listener when adding a new tab
    public ActionTabListener(NetworksFragment fragment) {
        frag = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {    
        ft.add(R.id.net_frag, frag, null);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(frag);        
    }
}
```

It seems like its putting two fragments (two copies) in the same activity.
Do you know what are causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are defining a fragment in XML, which will instantiate it when that layout is inflated (from NetworksActivity.setContentView(R.layout.networks)) then you are creating another instance of it just below that.

Unless I am missing something, that is your problem. No need to define it in XML if you are going to instantiate it manually and add it yourself in code.

Comment: This is correct. If you're going to add a fragment with the tab listener, you don't need to add it in the xml layout. It's being added once in the layout and again when you add it in the TabListener

Answer (score 0):

I had a **similar problem**. The way i **solved it** was to remove this code from my *Fragment-class*:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

CameraFragment cameraFragment = new CameraFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.spinnerFragment, spinnerFragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And **left** this code from my fragment-XML:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/spinnerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.SpinnerFragment" />
```

*I guess you can do it the oposite way also :)*